# Add product names to the dropdownlist using jquery from the text box

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, html-select

Hi i have got a dropdownlist and a text box , what i want is to add the product written in the textbox to the dropdownlist dynamically, it should also not duplicate the values.

I have created a table[products] with columns id and product , so the product added to the dropdownlist should be added to that table.

Any ideas on how to get that working , any help and suggestions will be appreciated

```
<div id="dropdown-container">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtProduct" runat="server"></asp:TextBox><a id="add"
        href="javascript:void(0)">Add</a>
    <select id="product">
    <option>please select</option>
 </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Please share what you have tried so far.

Comment: havnt done anything apart from writing some html to be honest

Answer (score 1):

Some code that might get you started. Hard to help you without seing the actual source.

In the textbox keyup event:

```
$(function(){

    $('#add').click(function(){

         var $productTextbox = $('#txtProduct');

         $.get('producthandler.ashx', 
               {  productName: $productTextbox.val() 

                     /* try to make use of 
                     an ID instead of name here */
               })
               .done(function(response){

                   var $option = 
                             $('<option>' + $productTextbox.val() + '</option>');

                   if(response.productDoesNotExist)
                       $('#product').append($option);
               }
         });


    });

});
```

If you provide me with how the actual datasource looks I can give you a more detailed example.

Comment: i have edit the question on what ihave done , i just dont know how to add those products to the sql table

Comment: well i m using asp.net , and i am using connection string to connect to the database , but the problem is i dont want postbacks , i want to add it dynamically to the db

Comment: @MrA I think you're trying to achieve an asynchronous call to the server. Have a look at jQuery.ajax

Comment: have u got any examples of jquery.ajax , which does the check and add in the table coz i need to check the table first if , the product exist then dont add to the dropdown list and table

Comment: @MrA Create a generic handler (.ashx) like I did above. This should get you started.